# Ios smsComposer phonegap plugin works with cordova-2.1.0 js file or not

Tags: ios5, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I am able to integrate iOS smsComposer phonegap plugin in cordova-1.9.0 but not able to integrate with cordova-2.1.0 js file. What could be the issue. Anyone worked on that plugin or is that plugin supports cordova-2.1.o or not and one more thing how to figure out whether phone gap plugins support our current cordova-x.x.x or not.

Comment: I am able to integrate smsComposer working fine with ios6 version devices but not woth ios5 version devices what may be issue any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of SMSComposer as of last month at
  [git phonegap plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/SMSComposer)

I have it working with cordova-2.2.0.js

NOTES:

- there's a file that they use: SMSComposer.js   I had to change "Cordova" to "cordova" to get it working.
- Also it is for older iOS versions.  I think I broke it by changing that in Xcode, the first time I worked w the plugin.